# Creating a matrix of dimension d with constraints on indices

Tags: matrix, constraint

Is there a way to create a matrix $q$ of dimension $d$  with constraints on the indices given by:

$$d\longrightarrow dimension$$

$i,j $ are indices

$$q_{i,j}=\begin{cases}
-b & j=i+d,\\
c & j=i+1,\\
l & j=d+i\pm1.
\end{cases}$$

$b,c,l$ are constants.

Comment: Define the function `q[i, j]` and then `matrix = Array[q, {d, d}]`

Comment: @Michael E2  I have done like:  Format[q[a_, b_]] := Subscript[q, Row@{a, b}];   d = 2;  q[i_, i_ + d] := -b     q[i_, i_ + 1] := c     q[i_, i_ + d + 1] := l   Array[q, {d, d}]   Not working

Comment: is $d$ symbolic or an explicit integer?

Comment: It’s just an interger 1,2,3,4…. anything

Comment: If the matrix is $d \times d$, how can there be components with $j = i + d$ or $j = d + i + 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a good job for Piecewise:

```
q[i_, j_] := Piecewise[{{-b, j == i + d}, {c, j == i + 1}, 
                        {l, j == d + i + 1}, {l, j == d + i - 1}}]
```

Now you can build the matrix:

```
d = 8; n = 15; (mat = Array[q, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

which gives the same answer as cvgmt.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe need to chack the definition of such matrix,it seems not right.

```
d = 8;
n = 15;
q=SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> 
   c, {i_, j_} /; j == i + d -> -b, {i_, j_} /; 
    j == d + i + 1 || j == d + i - 1 -> l}, {n, n}]
q//MatrixForm
```

Or

```
d = 8;
n = 15;
m = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1+1}] -> c, Band[{1, 1 + d}] -> -b, 
   Band[{1, d + 1 + 1}] -> l, Band[{1, d + 1 - 1}] -> l}, {n, n}]
m // MatrixForm
```